# Delay update from unread to read

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a notifications page where I want to show only the notifications that a user hasn't seen. I'm trying to do this by making each notification :read => false by default but changing it to :read => true when the user clicks on the notification link (the '.bell' class). The problem is it's changed to => true exactly when the user clicks on the link, so when the notification page loads everything has been 'read' and it displays nothing. I'm not sure how to delay this change until the page has been loaded.

In my controller I have this:

```
def notifications
  @activities = PublicActivity::Activity.order("created_at desc").where(recipient_id: current_user.id)
  @notification_count = @activities.where(:read => false).count  
end

def read_all_notifications
  PublicActivity::Activity.where(recipient_id: current_user.id).update_all(:read => true)
end
```

Then in my routes:

```
get 'users/:id/allnotifications', to: 'users#allnotifications', as: :allnotifications 
post 'users/read_all_notifications', to: 'users#read_all_notifications', as: :read_all_notifications
```

and in users.js.coffee:

```
$(document).on 'click' , '.bell' , (e)->
    $.ajax '/users/read_all_notifications' ,
        type: "post"
        dataType: "json"
        beforeSend: (xhr) ->
          xhr.setRequestHeader "X-CSRF-Token", $("meta[name=\"csrf-token\"]").attr("content")
        cache: false
```

**Edit**

I am now putting this at the bottom of my notifications view:

```
<script>
$(document) ()->
    $.ajax '/users/read_all_notifications' ,
       type: "post"
       dataType: "json"
       beforeSend: (xhr) ->
         xhr.setRequestHeader "X-CSRF-Token", $("meta[name=\"csrf-token\"]").attr("content")
       cache: false  
</script>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I may be totally under-thinking this but, any reason in your app/logic that you can't just use an [after_action](http://apidock.com/rails/v4.0.2/AbstractController/Callbacks/ClassMethods/after_action) in your controller?

**Controller**

```
after_action :read_all_notifications 

def notifications
  @activities = PublicActivity::Activity.order("created_at desc").where(recipient_id: current_user.id)
  @notification_count = @activities.where(:read => false).count  
end

def read_all_notifications
  PublicActivity::Activity.where(recipient_id: current_user.id).update_all(:read => true)
end
```

In theory, this would mark all unread notifications as read once the controller finished loading (and displaying) the page.

Again, I may well be under-thinking your issue and apologies if I have, but, I did want to offer this possible solution.

Answer (score 1):

**Attribute**

You'll be much better using one of the [`state_machine` gems](https://www.ruby-toolbox.com/categories/state_machines) ([`state_machine`](https://github.com/pluginaweek/state_machine), [`aasm`](http://github.com/aasm/aasm), `workflow`)

We use `aasm`, primarily because `state_machine` is no longer active.

```
#app/models/activity.rb
class Activity < ActiveRecord::Base
   include AASM

   aasm do
     state :unread, :initial => true
     state :read

     event :open do
       transitions :from => :unread, :to => :read
     end

     event :mark_as_read do
       transitions :from => :read, :to => :unread
     end
  end
end
```

This will "over engineer" your requirements, but will certainly provide you with the functionality you need to make it *extensible*

By including one of these gems, it will automatically populate the `state` attribute in your table. This is both more verbose & less succinct than using a standard boolean, but what it *really* helps you do is provide you with *object orientated* public methods:

```
job = Job.new
job.sleeping? # => true
job.may_run?  # => true
job.run
job.running?  # => true
job.sleeping? # => false
job.may_run?  # => false
job.run       # => raises AASM::InvalidTransition
```

In your case, you'll have:

```
notification = PublicActivity::Activity.new

notification.read? # -> false
notification.unread? #-> true

notification.mark_as_read #-> "unread"
noticiation.open  #-> "read"
notification.sate #-> "unread"
```

---

**Associations**

Secondly, you'll need to use associations & [scopes](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#scopes) to manage your data.

Any time you call `.where` on a [`foreign_key`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Foreign_key), you're doing the work which ActiveRecord *could* be doing for you:

```
#app/models/public_activity/activity.rb
class PublicActivity::Activity < ActiveRecord::Base
   #fields id | user_id | created_at | updated_at

   belongs_to :user
   #belongs_to :recipient, class_name: "User", foreign_key: "recipient_id" #-> received --only if user to user

   scope :recent, -> { order created_at: desc }
   scope :read,   -> { where status: "read" }
end

#app/models/users.rb
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
   has_many :notifications, class_name: "PublicActivity::Activity"
end
```

This should give you the ability to call the following:

```
current_user.notifications.recent.read
```

---

**Transition**

> so when the notification page loads everything has been 'read' and it
>   displays nothing. I'm not sure how to delay this change until the page
>   has been loaded.

From what I understand of your request, just use a delayed ajax request:

```
#config/routes.rb
resources :users do
  resources :notifications, only: [:index, :show] do
      post :read_all, on: :collection #-> domain.com/notifications/read_all
  end
end
```

This will give you the ability to use the following:

```
#app/controllers/notifications_controller.rb
class NotificationsController < ApplicationController
  # before_action :set_user -> only needed if not using current_user

   def index
      @notifications = current_user.notifications
   end

   private

   def set_user
      @user = User.find params[:user_id]
   end
end
```

It will give you the ability to use a delayed Ajax request as follows:

```
#app/assets/javascripts/delayed_ajax.js
jQuery(document).ready(function () {
    setTimeout(update_read, 1000);
});

var update_read = function() {
   $.ajax({
      url: "users/....../read_all",
      success: function(data) {
          alert("Success");
      }
   });
};
```

The above javascript will have to be called explicitly from the view you wish to use it in (or at least have some identifying value to determine when it fires).

The trick here will be that it uses *ajax*. The importance of this is that the Ajax will only work *after* the page has loaded (ensuring your issue is not repeated), and it will only fire after a certain amount of time.

This should work for you

Comment: I tried to follow your aasm suggestion but stopped at the first problem. Just getting notifications working was hard enough and think its a little too much for me. But, your delayed ajax example is exactly what I want. Do you mind showing me how I could get it to work without aasm (as well as how to call delayed_ajax.js from my view)? I appreciate the help :)

Comment: Love this but I got lost where the `Activity` association is happening with `PublicActivity::Activity`

Answer (score 1):

I may be missing some of the issue here, but i believe you want a result where when they click on the notifications page, it renders all of the unread notifications, keeps the unread number at the current state.
If they user goes to another page, they will now see 0 unread notifications (assuming no new notifications have been created) and if they click the link again will see no notifications.

If that is the case, a very simple solution would be

```
def notifications
  #Get UNREAD activities AND force execution
  @activities = PublicActivity::Activity.order("created_at desc").where(recipient_id: current_user.id).where(:read => false).all
  @notification_count = @activities.where(:read => false).count  
  #Mark items read
  PublicActivity::Activity.where(recipient_id: current_user.id).where(:read => false).update_all(:read => true)
end
```

Note. The queries changed slightly. the .all should force execution of the query.

Comment: Thanks for the help. I tried something like this but I think i needed the 'after_action' to make it work. Thanks again.

Comment: yup, after_action is better

Answer (score 0):

I would remove the listener on the click, and would add it to the page when it is loaded instead. That way, once the page is loaded, the ajax request is triggered.

I assume you have a notifications template file (notifications.html.erb maybe?). That's where you should require your js call to trigger the "mark all as read". Be careful not to keep the js trigger in users.js.coffee as that javascript file is probably loaded on every request and not only when notifications template is loaded.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. New to js so bear with me. What should I replace the '$(document).on 'click' , '.bell' , (e)->' line with instead?

Comment: It would be something like $(document) ()-> (as that's the call for document load using jquery) but again you cant just add it into your users.js.coffee file. You'd still need to add the js snippet call to the notifications template, after it is rendered.

Comment: Hmm, still no luck. I edited the question with what I now have in my view.